# HTML5 videojs player prototype mode

Tags: html5-video, video.js

I've just started using the HTML5 videojs player (as in videojs.com). I started modifying and personalizing it.

I can't remember at which point it appeared, but I now get a sort of progress text rendered beneath the video player in my browser. From what I can work out `video.js` is calling some sort of `prototype` function to `print` this info. Anyone know how I can turn it off?

This is what appears beneath the video on the web page and I can't see how to turn it off?

```
Play 
Current Time 0:38 
Duration Time 0:39 
Remaining Time -0:00 
Stream TypeLIVE 
Loaded: 0% 
Progress: 0% 0:38 
Fullscreen 00:00 
Mute 
Playback Rate
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with css for some reason it sometimes doesn't work locally so try to use external css from videojs.com in header instead.

```
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.11/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Hi Sim. Many thanks.  I can't use this external CCS site, because I've modified the CSS so much.  It's a bit late to go through it and put all the modi factions into a separate file.  However, I'll try and put it onto another of my sites and see it that cures it.

Comment: what you could do is this you could use local by putting the css in header instead since you have customized it example http://jsfiddle.net/ao2z5qa7/